# the integral of $1/(x\sqrt{4x+1})$

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals, radicals

I integrated $\frac{1}{x\sqrt{4x + 1}}$ and got I $\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{4x+1}-1}{2\sqrt{x}}\right| + K$, where K is a constant term. But my book gives the answer as $\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{4x+1}-1}{\sqrt{4x+1} + 1}\right| + K$. Where did I make a mistake?

[Here is how I solved it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgehy.jpg)

Comment: you can replace sqrt by \sqrt{}. Further please use dollar signs around for mathematical expressions

Comment: Got it. Sorry I don't use this much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\sqrt{4x+1}=t$.

Hence, $\frac{4}{2t}dx=dt$ and $x=\frac{t^2-1}{4}$.

Thus,
$$\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{4x+1}}dx=2\int\frac{1}{t^2-1}dt=\int\left(\frac{1}{t-1}-\frac{1}{t+1}\right)dt=\ln\left|\frac{t-1}{t+1}\right|+C$$

Comment: You just bet me! +1.

Comment: Ah I see thank you. Did you see my solution? Is the way I went about it valid?

Comment: @thestackneverends My solution gives your answer exactly.

Comment: Actually I got $ln|(\sqrt{4x+1}-1)/(2\sqrt{x})| + K$ Is that equivalent to your answer? Please check the image I attached to the original question.

Comment: @Sir know-a-ton I meant the answer of the book. But thank you! I'll delete my previous comment.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg Cool yea, but my question is whether my solution is valid. I attached my solution in an image. Please give it a look to see whether it is mathematically valid.

Comment: @Sir know-a-ton Your solution is very nice, but the mistake in  calculating of  $\int\frac{1}{\sin\theta}d\theta$

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg What it the mistake? $1/sin(x) = csc(x)$ and the integral of $csc(x)$ is $ln|csc(x) - cot(x)| + K$ So I am not sure what mistake you are talking about.

Comment: @Sir know-a-ton By your way $\int\frac{1}{\sin\theta}d\theta=\ln\left|\frac{1}{\sin\theta}-\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}\right|+C=\ln\frac{1-\cos\theta}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}}+C=\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{1-\cos\theta}{1+\cos\theta}+C$.